# How to see Clojure local variables in local repl?

Tags: clojure, binding, var, read-eval-print-loop

I want to play around and develop expressions based on local variables by placing a repl (with clojure.main/repl) inside a function body:

```
(ns something)

(defn myfunc [ p ]
   (let [local (+ p 10)]
        (clojure.main/repl)
        (+ local 100)))

(myfunc 666)
```

When I executed this, the repl starts ok, but the parameters of the function and local let-bindings do not seem to be visible in the prompt:

```
something=> p
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: p in this context
something=> local
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: local in this context
```

I have been able to pass the values by creating new ^:dynamic vars and setting their values locally with binding, but this is quite complex and requires separate binding for each local variable:

```
(def ^:dynamic x)

(defn myfunc [ p ]
   (let [local (+ p 10)]
        (binding [x local]
                 (clojure.main/repl))
        (+ local 100)))
```

Is there simpler way to pass/access local values in such local repl? Or is there some better way to do access the local variables from non-local repl, such as the "lein repl"?

Comment: You may be able to use the `repl` fn's `:init` hook to define variables.

Comment: Thank you, :init looks promising. The docs say ":init, function of no arguments, initialization hook called with bindings for set!-able vars in place." But I was not able to find with some googling any example how to use :init for passing the values, are you able to provide one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `:init` hook, you can define arbitrary vars in the REPL namespace.

```
(defn myfunc [p]
  (let [local (+ p 10)]
    (clojure.main/repl :init #(do (def p p) (def local local)))
    (+ local 100)))
```

Here's a `repl` macro to make adding a breakpoint easier:

```
(defmacro locals []
  (into {}
        (map (juxt name identity))
        (keys &env)))

(defn defs [vars]
  (doseq [[k v] vars]
    (eval (list 'def (symbol k) (list 'quote v)))))

(defmacro repl []
  `(let [ls# (locals)]
     (clojure.main/repl :init #(defs ls#))))
```

Now you can just drop in `(repl)`:

```
(defn myfunc [p]
  (let [local (+ p 10)]
    (repl)
    (+ local 100)))
```

Comment: This `defs` function is not correct. Try it with a local whose value is the list `(1 2 3)`: it will try calling `1` as a function. You should at least quote the value: `(eval (list 'def (symbol k) (list 'quote v)))`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a good answer for using the repl, but I favor using good old-fashioned printouts.  This is facilitated by the `spyx`, `let-spy`, and `let-spy-pretty` macros:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn myfunc [ p ]
  (spyx p)
  (let-spy [local (+ p 10)]
    (+ local 100)))

(dotest
  (spyx (myfunc 666)))
```

with result:

```
p              => 666
local          => 676
(myfunc 666)   => 776
```

Documentation on `spyx` & friends [is here in the README](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#expression-debugging), and there is also [full API documentation on GitHub pages](http://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/).

Comment: Thanks for the spy information! This can definitely be a good tool in my debugging toolbox. I still also keep looking for way to use repl on-the-spot since my main use for that would be to faciliate development of new expressions feeding on existing values (rather than just viewing existing values)